# Tensors and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, tensors

The tensor T represents a rotation of a vector $\vec{a}$ of degree $\phi$ on the $z$-axis and it stretches the vector by the scalar a such that

$$\vec b=\begin{bmatrix}b_x\\b_y\\b_z\end{bmatrix}=T\vec\alpha=T\begin{bmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{bmatrix}$$

I know how to do the first part, so if it rotates about the $z$-axis by $\phi$, then

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi)&-
\sin(\phi)&0\\ \sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I'm not quite sure how the stretching would look like, can tensors do that? Am I supposed to multiply all elements by a?